# Attach multiple files via Android Intent, works with one file, but not multiple

Tags: java, android, android-intent, email-attachments

If I build the intent with just one attached file using a simple:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, detailsuri);
```

... then it works. But if I try to attach multiple files using

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
```

... then it doesn't attach anything. I can attach each of the files successfully when I do it one at a time. So it's not a problem with either of the files. Here is the full code which creates the files, gets the uris, and builds the intent.

What am I missing? Why can't I attach multiple files?

```
File outputDir = controller.getDocumentStorageDir();

String jsontext = buildDbText();

File dbfile = new File(outputDir, "db.json");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(dbfile);
writer.write(jsontext);
writer.close();

Uri jsondburi = Uri.fromFile(dbfile);

String appdetails = buildDetailsText();

File detailsfile = new File(outputDir, "details.txt");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(detailsfile);
writer.write(appdetails);
writer.close();

Uri detailsuri = Uri.fromFile(detailsfile);


Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { custsupportEmail });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailbody);

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
uris.add(detailsuri);
uris.add(jsondburi);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        Uri uri =  FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
        Uri uri2 =  FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file2);
        intentShareFile.setType("text/*");

        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
        uris.add(uri);
        uris.add(uri2);

        intentShareFile.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, file.getName());
        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share " + file.getName() + file2.getName());
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share " + file.getName() + file2.getName()));
```

Answer (score -2):

W/Bundle: Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected Parcelable but value was a java.util.ArrayList.  The default value  was returned.

Comment: Uri -does- implement Parcelable. `public abstract class Uri 
extends Object implements Parcelable, Comparable<Uri>`

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thank you for correcting me.